# Migrating From ExchangeWebService Basic Authentication to OAuth2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

My goal is to migrate our Exchange connection to use OAuth2.0 so we are covered for the 2020 removal of Basic Authentication.

My Current Code using Basic Authentication is:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(MailBox, Password, "domamer");
try
{
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(MailBox, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
}
catch
{
    service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
}
```

Reviewing the documentation provided by Microsoft Here: ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth?redirectedfrom=MSDN))
I coded the following, with the expectation that it would replace the above.

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
{
    ClientId = AppSettings.GetOauthClientID(),
    TenantId = AppSettings.GetOauthTenantID()
};

var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

// The permission scope required for EWS access
var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

// Make the interactive token request
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

// Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, MailBox);
```

I thought "ewsClient" in my new code would be the equivalent of "service" in my original code.

When I try to step through my project, it just ends at this line:

```
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

I've double checked my ClientID, TenantID are correct.

Has anyone had this problem before?  Possible solutions or things to check?

I tried using the Try/Catch in hopes of getting an error message, but I never hit the breakpoints I set on all the Console.WriteLine.  It just locks up and stops responding at the ExecuteAsync() line

```
try
{
    // Make the interactive token request
    var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

    // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
    var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
    ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
    ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, EmailBox);

    Console.WriteLine("Made it Here");
}
catch (MsalException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex.ToString()}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: You should be wrapping you MSAL authentication in a Try Catch block(like the example) which should then give you access to the MSAL exception which will help tell you what is wrong. Have you consented to the use of the Application Registration you created ?

Comment: I tried with the try/catch, and it still skips over everything.  I never hit the breakpoints on the errors.  I have granted Consent to all Mail, User, and Exchange API permissions.  Status shows Granted for all.

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint after the authResult what is in that ? You can use something like fiddler to look at the Auth Request and response that are being sent to the server (which I find is the easiest way of debuging auth issue)

Comment: A breakpoint after authResult is never reached.

Comment: In Fiddler, I get a Tunnel to login.microsoftonline.com, status 200.  Then nothing.

Comment: you need to select the option to decode https traffic

Comment: After enabling decode https, I get a second login status 200, then a vortex.data.microsoft that has a status 200.  Nothing sticks out to me.  Is there a specific thing you recommend looking at in Fiddler?

Comment: @MrMatt Have you had any success with this? We're about to hit the same wall as you and could do with a hand before too long.

Comment: @StuartFrankish, I just posted the solution that I got from a call with Microsoft Support.  I was hopeful a cleaner solution might come up, but it does the job and gets the authorization token for OAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Microsoft on the phone, they struggled to help me get it working as well.  It took a while, but I was finally able to make an OAuth connection to Microsoft Services using the following code:

```
private const string TenantID = "[Your Tenant ID]";
private const string ClientID = "[Your Client ID]";
private const string ClientSecret = "[Your Secret ID]";

private const string AgentName = "My Agent Name";

public static ExchangeService OAuthConnectPost()
{
    string LoginURL = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", TenantID);

    var LogValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
        { "client_id", ClientID },
        { "client_secret", ClientSecret },
        { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
    };
    string postData = "";
    foreach (var v in LogValues)
    {
        postData += (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postData) ? "" : "&") + v.Key + "=" + v.Value;
    }
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginURL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.UserAgent = AgentName;
    request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var aToken = JObject.Parse(json)["access_token"].ToString();

        var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
        ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(aToken);
        return ewsClient;
    }
}
```

I can then make a connection to the service and authenticate using a user account similar to what I was doing before

```
var service = OAuthConnectPost();
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailBox, EmailPass, EmailDomain);
FolderId rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
ItemView view = new ItemView(500);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(rootFolderId, view);
```

Comment: I observed that whatever OAuthCredentials you are passing while requesting ExchangeService are again overridden by web credentials.  i.e ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(aToken); become service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailBox, EmailPass, EmailDomain);. Can you please help me understand, does it not overriding Oauth to Basic Authentication?

Comment: I do that to read a specific email box.  I hope it's still authenticated with OAuth, but It's opening a specific email box.

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string TenantID = "[Your Tenant ID]";
private const string ClientID = "[Your Client ID]";
private const string ClientSecret = "[Your Secret ID]";

private const string AgentName = "My Agent Name";

public static ExchangeService OAuthConnectPost()
{
    string LoginURL = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", TenantID);

    var LogValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "client_id", ClientID },
            { "client_secret", ClientSecret },
            { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
        };
    string postData = "";
    foreach (var v in LogValues)
    {
        postData += (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postData) ? "" : "&") + v.Key + "=" + v.Value;
    }
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginURL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.UserAgent = AgentName;
    request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var aToken = JObject.Parse(json)["access_token"].ToString();

        var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
        ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(aToken);
        ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
            new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "user@domain.com");
        ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "user@domain.com");


        return ewsClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference—if any—between this and @MrMatt's original answer? On quick glance, the code looks very similar, if not identical. And without an explanation, it's hard to tell what this is doing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added the impersonation of an user because the first solution was overwritten the oauth authentication to basic authentication when this line of code was executed 


service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailBox, EmailPass, EmailDomain);

ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
            new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "user@domain.com");
        ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "user@domain.com");